# Library not found for -lxml2 with xmpp while building IPA file in xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, xmppframework

I am making a chat app with xmpp framework.

I have setup XMPPFramework in my project by referring this link:-

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-interface-setup--mobile-7188

When i build IPA i getting error like :
library is not found for -lxml2. i also try to change User Search path and Header path but still it generate same error.

Can anyone suggest me solution for this.
thanx in adv.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have added libxml2 (.dylib or .tbd) to your "Link Binary with Libraries" section? Isn't it colored red?

> i also try to change User Search path and Header path

Change to what? For me, libxml2.dylib is present in a standard location: /usr/lib => no need to change anything. Do you have it there, too?

Comment: when i not changed any path at time it seen RED, but now i add libxml2 in my project . it still generate error.

Comment: It's hard to help you if you avoid answering direct questions :)

Comment: no libxml2 is not showing red in "Link Binary with Libraries"

Comment: OK, great, and the rest of the questions? :) Well, I'll repeat them: 1) Is there libxml2.dylib or libxml2.tbd or libxml2.2.dylib or libxml2.2.tbd in your "Link Binary with Libraries" section (colored black)? 2) Which of them, exactly? 3) Is this file (from #2) really present in your /usr/lib folder? 4) You said you changed "User Search path" and "Header path". You changed them to what? And 5) what are exactly these options names? I haven't found any of these in Xcode 6 / 7.

Comment: 1) libxml2 with black color.

Comment: 2) m not get path of usr/lib

Comment: 3) i change it to $(include) /usr/include/libxml2

Answer (score 0):

You have two option to solve this problem :

You can add the flag `-lxml2` to your `OTHER_LDFLAGS` in your `TARGET BUILD SETTINGS`, and add in your `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` : `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2`

Or you can use a wrapper around the `XMPPFramework`, witch will handle all the compile problems for you.

You can check it out [here](https://github.com/processone/xmpp-messenger-ios).

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `Security.frameWork` in Linked Frameworks and libraries
2. Add in `User Header Search Paths : $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2` make it `recursive`
3. Add in `Header Search Paths : $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2` make it `non-recursive`
4. search "Other Linker Flags" and the add: `-lxml2`.
5. Now clean project and build for IPA
   [Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntlbN.png)